# is it possible to debug an msbuild 15 script with VS 2017?

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-15

There is this old article - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2010/07/06/debugging-msbuild-script-with-visual-studio/

But it does not seem relevant for msbuild 15.